# How to give time labels consistently in polar highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular7

Hi i am working on highcharts i am having a polar chart and i wanna display on y-axis time consistently. This is the one which i tried so far:

Here my labels are `[06:00,08:00,.....20:00]`

But how to make consistency like upto `24:00, 02:00, 04:00` so that i will be able to hover some of the values which i cant see properly now.

And my expected outcome should be like this: `[02:00, 04:00, ......24:00]`

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'scatter',
      },
      
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          showLastLabel: true, 
        },
        time: {
        useUTC: false
      },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0
  },

  series: [{
    data: [
        [1616718600000, 145],
  [1616721000000, 145],
  [1616721900000, 145],
  [1616722500000, 145],
  [1616736300000, 145],
  [1616738700000, 145],
  [1616738700000, 145],
  [1616739900000, 145],
  [1616739900000, 145],
  [1616740500000, 145],
  [1616742300000, 145],
  [1616742600000, 145],
  [1616742900000, 145],
  [1616742900000, 145],
  [1616762100000, 145],
  [1616762700000, 145],
  [1616763600000, 145],
  [1616763600000, 145],
  [1616763600000, 145],
  [1616763900000, 145],
  [1616763900000, 145],
  [1616763900000, 145],
  [1616764200000, 145],
  [1616764200000, 145],
  [1616764500000, 145],
  [1616764500000, 145],
  [1616764500000, 145],
  [1616764500000, 145],
  [1616764800000, 145],
  [1616764800000, 145],
  [1616764800000, 145],
  [1616765100000, 145],
  [1616765400000, 145],
  [1616765400000, 145],
  [1616765400000, 145],
  [1616765400000, 145],
  [1616765400000, 145],
  [1616765700000, 145],
  [1616765700000, 145],
  [1616765700000, 145],
  [1616766000000, 145],
  [1616766000000, 145],
  [1616766300000, 145],
  [1616766300000, 145],
  [1616766300000, 145],
  [1616766600000, 145],
  [1616767200000, 145],
  [1616767200000, 145],
  [1616767500000, 145],
  [1616767500000, 145],
  [1616767500000, 145],
  [1616768100000, 145],
  [1616768400000, 145],
  [1616768400000, 145],
  [1616768700000, 145],
  [1616771400000, 145],
  [1616773500000, 145],
  [1616773800000, 145],
  [1616773800000, 145],
  [1616773800000, 145],
  [1616774100000, 145],
  [1616774400000, 145],
  [1616774400000, 145],
  [1616774400000, 145],
  [1616774700000, 145],
  [1616774700000, 145],
  [1616774700000, 145],
  [1616774700000, 145],
  [1616774700000, 145],
  [1616774700000, 145],
  [1616774700000, 145],
  [1616775300000, 145],
  [1616775300000, 145],
  [1616775300000, 145],
  [1616775300000, 145],
  [1616775300000, 145],
  [1616775300000, 145],
  [1616775900000, 145],
  [1616775900000, 145],
  [1616776200000, 145],
        ]
  },
  {
  data: [
   [1616718600000, 145],
 [1616721000000, 145],
 [1616721900000, 145],
 [1616722500000, 145],
 [1616736300000, 145],
 [1616737800000, 145],
 [1616737800000, 145],
 [1616738400000, 145],
 [1616738700000, 145],
 [1616738700000, 145],
 [1616738700000, 145],
 [1616738700000, 145],
 [1616738700000, 145],
 [1616739000000, 145],
 [1616739000000, 145],
 [1616739000000, 145],
 [1616739000000, 145],
 [1616739300000, 145],
 [1616739300000, 145],
 [1616739300000, 145],
 [1616739900000, 145],
 [1616739900000, 145],
 [1616739900000, 145],
 [1616739900000, 145],
 [1616740500000, 145],
 [1616740500000, 145],
 [1616740500000, 145],
 [1616740500000, 145],
 [1616740500000, 145],
 [1616741400000, 145],
 [1616741400000, 145],
 [1616741400000, 145],
 [1616741700000, 145],
 [1616741700000, 145],
 [1616742000000, 145],
 [1616742300000, 145],
 [1616742300000, 145],
 [1616742300000, 145],
 [1616742600000, 145],
 [1616742600000, 145],
 [1616742900000, 145],
 [1616742900000, 145],
 [1616742900000, 145],
 [1616742900000, 145],
 [1616743200000, 145],
 [1616743800000, 145],
 [1616743800000, 145],
 [1616744100000, 145],
 [1616744100000, 145],
 [1616745600000, 145],
 [1616746500000, 145],
 [1616746800000, 145],
 [1616762100000, 145],
 [1616762700000, 145],
 [1616763600000, 145],
 [1616763600000, 145],
 [1616763600000, 145],
 [1616763900000, 145],
 [1616763900000, 145],
 [1616763900000, 145],
 [1616764200000, 145],
 [1616764200000, 145],
 [1616764500000, 145],
 [1616764500000, 145],
 [1616764500000, 145],
 [1616764500000, 145],
 [1616764500000, 145],
 [1616764800000, 145],
 [1616764800000, 145],
 [1616764800000, 145],
 [1616765100000, 145],
 [1616765400000, 145],
 [1616765400000, 145],
 [1616765400000, 145],
 [1616765400000, 145],
 [1616765400000, 145],
 [1616765700000, 145],
 [1616765700000, 145],
 [1616765700000, 145],
 [1616766000000, 145],
 [1616766000000, 145],
 [1616766300000, 145],
 [1616766300000, 145],
 [1616766300000, 145],
 [1616766600000, 145],
 [1616766600000, 145],
 [1616767200000, 145],
 [1616767200000, 145],
 [1616767500000, 145],
 [1616767500000, 145],
 [1616767500000, 145],
 [1616768100000, 145],
 [1616768400000, 145],
 [1616768400000, 145],
 [1616768700000, 145],
 [1616771400000, 145],
 [1616772900000, 145],
 [1616772900000, 145],
 [1616773200000, 145],
 [1616773500000, 145],
 [1616773500000, 145],
 [1616773800000, 145],
 [1616773800000, 145],
 [1616773800000, 145],
 [1616773800000, 145],
 [1616774100000, 145],
 [1616774100000, 145],
 [1616774400000, 145],
 [1616774400000, 145],
 [1616774400000, 145],
 [1616774400000, 145],
 [1616774400000, 145],
 [1616774700000, 145],
 [1616774700000, 145],
 [1616774700000, 145],
 [1616774700000, 145],
 [1616774700000, 145],
 [1616774700000, 145],
 [1616774700000, 145],
 [1616774700000, 145],
 [1616774700000, 145],
 [1616775000000, 145],
 [1616775000000, 145],
 [1616775300000, 145],
 [1616775300000, 145],
 [1616775300000, 145],
 [1616775300000, 145],
 [1616775300000, 145],
 [1616775300000, 145],
 [1616775300000, 145],
 [1616775300000, 145],
 [1616775300000, 145],
 [1616775300000, 145],
 [1616775600000, 145],
 [1616775900000, 145],
 [1616775900000, 145],
 [1616775900000, 145],
 [1616775900000, 145],
 [1616776200000, 145],
 [1616776200000, 145],
 [1616776500000, 145],
 [1616776500000, 145],
 [1616776500000, 145],
 [1616776500000, 145],
 [1616776800000, 145],
 [1616776800000, 145]
  ]
  }
  ]
});
```

Here is the demo:  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xm86b09/21/)

Any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `min` and `max` properties with the right value.

```
    xAxis: {
        ...
        min: 1616716800000,
        max: 1616716800000 + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // + 24h
        labels: {
            formatter: function(){
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H: %M', this.value);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xctqfhd2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min

Comment: This looks good but the values when i hover gives the wrong values. i.e., the values not matching with the axis values. I think that min value should be dynamic instead of static value.

Comment: Hi @kishan, Yes of courese, you need to adapt `min` value to your data.